Option "Automatically link work items included in this run" is not available
When selecting 'Settings' for our YAML pipeline running, as suggested in the online docs, the option "Automatically link work items included in this run" is not available.
Is there some prerequisite that must be in place for this option to appear?
(We are using a GitHub repository, btw, not Azure Repos.)

Go to Project Settings -> Overview. Check whether Boards is turned on. If not, turn it on.

If Boards is disabled, the related features will be unavailable, including "Automatically link work items included in this run".

Update
According to official doc,

As with Azure Repos, you can link work items to pipeline objects with the following link types: Build, Integrated in build, and Integrated in release.

"Automatically link work items included in this run" only supports Azure repo and doesn't support GitHub repo.

Thanks, but we already have this turned on.

@Ola Eldøy, Currently, "Automatically link work items included in this run" only supports Azure repo and doesn't support GitHub repo. I notice that you have created a feature request, I have helped you submit a vote. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. Hope this feature can be supported in the further.
